# Custom Fields are not Displaying on Lead Page Layout During Creation

Tags: custom-field, leads, standard-objects

I have created custom lead fields (one currency field, one date field) and added them to the page layout of a custom lead record type. I have verified the page layout assignment is correct.

When creating the lead through the console UI, the default leads console tab, I am only presented the standard fields.

After saving the new lead, the custom lead fields for that record type are displayed on the page layout.

Is this functionality expected or is something wrong here?

Comment: Can you cast more light on the type of the fields you created? For example, Formula fields are not shown in the Edit mode.

Comment: Can you check the FLS for those fields for the profile you are using to access the page?

Comment: @Eduard Field types added into question.

Comment: @BobGali Read/Write object permissions confirmed for the custom fields, record type, and lead object. FLS also confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lead as a standard object uses global action New Lead with a defined page layout - you have to add your fields there to see them in Create mode. (setup/global actions - New Lead - layout)